# favorite tags on ipad ios StackExchange beta app

Tags: feature-request, status-bydesign, tags, ios-app, bookmarks

It would be nice if the tags view on the Stack Exchange app showed a users favorite tags under the tags section for a given community.  I use them to browse questions for tags that I care about because the default activity page doesn't highlight the questions I really care to answer.

It would be nice if the favorite tags showed up above the popular tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pre-requisite: you must be logged into the app for this to work.

1. Scroll to the top of the tags listing
2. Tap on the arrow icons
3. Choose "Favorite"

[image]

Comment: Nice, it even allows wildcarded favourites. Is there any way to remember the order, so it shows the favourites by default? (And the sort order for questions within the tag, but that might already be a separate question)

Comment: @AlexPoole the app will save the sort order per site. Also, the order for questions within the tag is a new feature that should start working as of version 1.1.0.124