# Missing favourite tags in iOS app

Tags: bug, status-norepro, ios-app, tag-watching

I just came across [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/239789/233816) question which gave me the one feature I ever wanted in the app - easy access to my favourite tags. Unfortunately, some of them seem to be missing.

By missing, I mean - simply not on the list. I've tried deleting and redownloading which has no effect. The only potential pattern I'm able to spot, is that the missing tags are the last X tags in the list, as they are ordered on the SE sites - which I *think* equates to them being my most recently added favourites.

The full data set:

### Stack Overflow

My favourites are: [jquery-tokeninput](/questions/tagged/jquery-tokeninput) [tinybutstrong](/questions/tagged/tinybutstrong) [opentbs](/questions/tagged/opentbs) [tag-it](/questions/tagged/tag-it) [magicsuggest](/questions/tagged/magicsuggest) [tortoisehg](/questions/tagged/tortoisehg)

Missing from the app are: [magicsuggest](/questions/tagged/magicsuggest) [tortoisehg](/questions/tagged/tortoisehg)

### Music SE

My favourites are: [clarinet](/questions/tagged/clarinet) [wind-band](/questions/tagged/wind-band) [woodwinds](/questions/tagged/woodwinds) [instruments](/questions/tagged/instruments) [instrumentation](/questions/tagged/instrumentation) [instrument-cleaning](/questions/tagged/instrument-cleaning) [instrument-care](/questions/tagged/instrument-care) [maintenance](/questions/tagged/maintenance) [bass-clarinet](/questions/tagged/bass-clarinet) [saxophone](/questions/tagged/saxophone)

Missing from the app are: [saxophone](/questions/tagged/saxophone)

Comment: I believe this is an API caching issue. Did you add those  favorites to your list recently? (within a few minutes of looking at them in the app)

Comment: @ArieLitovsky no, probably a few months ago I added the oldest ones.

Comment: @ArieLitovsky Just FYI, this is ongoing, my tags still haven't appeared.

Comment: thanks for the update, I'll try to investigate again, though last time I could not reproduce

Comment: Think I've sussed it @Arie. For interests sake: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/254214/233816

Answer (score 2, accepted):

3 months later, my tags seem to have finally resynced. Whether something was fixed, or some cache just expired, I don't know!

Comment: Glad to hear! Most likely a caching problem.