# Favourite tag bugs in iOS app

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app, tag-watching

1. I added [ios-app](/questions/tagged/ios-app) to my favourites probably a few months ago...it still hasn't shown up in my app. Same problem as previously [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/240059/233816).
2. Refreshing the favourite tags page with no tags seems to make the text do crazy things!

[image][image][image]

I'm on iPhone 4S, iOS 8.1.3, app v1.2.2.198

Answer (score 1):

This will be fixed in the next build. The logic placed the label in the center of the table's bounds, but the table's bounds are dynamic and represent what is currently on the screen.  Sooo... the label was perfectly center at the exact moment when it appeared and then flew up as the table sprung back to its original position.  Now I'm just setting the center to (width/2, height/2).

Comment: Cool, any news on the first part - my missing favourite tags? Still not there even after deleting an reinstalling for the other bug :-(