# "No favourite tags" texts loses centring

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app, tag-watching

Very much a regression of [this guy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/250996/233816) - when refreshing the favourite tags page with no favourite tags, the text pings up to the top left corner. (It's more predictable this time.)

> [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next build.  What's happening is that when you refresh it actually removes the old label and puts a new one in.  It was then telling the `self.tableView` to update its layout when it should have been telling `self.view`. In the past `self.tableView == self.view` so the code worked.