# Is there a way to edit my favorite tags in the iPad app?

Tags: feature-request, support, ios-app, ipad

Does the new iPad app have a way to edit my favorite tags for a community? Or for that matter, to filter my view of the community by my favorite tags?

Answer (score 2):

There is currently no way to edit your favorite tags from the app.

You can see your favorite tags from the tags listing by choosing the "Favorite" sort. See [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239826/232374).

You can also see unanswered questions (from the question listing) based on your favorite tags by choosing the "Unanswered: My Tags" sort. The steps are similar to the screenshot in the linked answer.

Comment: Thanks for the link!if there isn't already a feature request for tag management, can this be considered one? 

Comment: Sure, we can update the question to reflect that